# knapsack case r implementation for multiple persons using genetic algorithm

Tags: r, mathematical-optimization, genetic-algorithm, knapsack-problem

I am trying to implement genetic algorithm in R. I found out that r has 'GA' and 'genalg' packages for genetic algorithm implementation. I encountered the example i the link http://www.r-bloggers.com/genetic-algorithms-a-simple-r-example/. They tried solving the Knapsack problem. The problem can be briefly explained as:
"You are going to spend a month in the wilderness. You’re taking a backpack with you, however, the maximum weight it can carry is 20 kilograms. You have a number of survival items available, each with its own number of 'survival points'. You’re objective is to maximize the number of survival points"

The problem is easily solved using 'genalg' package for a single person and the output is binary string. Now i have a doubt, lets say instead of one person there are 2 or more i.e multiple persons and we need to distribute the survival points. The weight constraints apply for each person. Then how can we solve this problem? Can we use 'genalg' or 'GA' package? If so how can we apply them? Are there any examples on this that are solved in R or other software's?

Thanks

Comment: You may also have a look on the relatively new R package ompr, which may easily be applied to your problem.. https://github.com/dirkschumacher/ompr

Answer (score 1):

The R package adagio (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/adagio/index.html) comes with two functions (knapsack and mknapsack) which solves this type of problem more efficient by dynamic programming.

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach could be to have one chromosome containing all individuals in the group and have the evaluation function split this chromosome in multiple parts, one for each individual and then have these parts evaluated. In the example below (based on the example in the question) I have assumed each individual has the same weight limit and multiple individuals can bring the same item.

```
library(genalg)

#Set up the problem parameters
#how many people in the group
individual_count <-3
#The weight limit for one individual
weightlimit <- 20
#The items with their survivalpoints
dataset <- data.frame(item = c("pocketknife", "beans", "potatoes", "unions", 
                               "sleeping bag", "rope", "compass"), survivalpoints = c(10, 20, 15, 2, 30, 
                                                                                      10, 30), weight = c(1, 5, 10, 1, 7, 5, 1))
#Next, we choose the number of iterations, design and run the model.
iter <- 100
#Our chromosome has to be large enough to contain a bit for all individuals and for all items in the dataset
chromosomesize <- individual_count * nrow(dataset)


#Function definitions
#A function to split vector X in N equal parts
split_vector <- function(x,n) split(x, cut(seq_along(x), n, labels = FALSE)) 

#EValuate an individual (a part of the chromosome)
evalIndividual <- function(x) {
  current_solution_survivalpoints <- x %*% dataset$survivalpoints
  current_solution_weight <- x %*% dataset$weight
  if (current_solution_weight > weightlimit) 
    return(0) else return(-current_solution_survivalpoints) 
}

#Evaluate a chromosome
evalFunc <- function(x) {
  #First split the chromosome in a list of individuals, then we can evaluate all individuals 
  individuals<-split_vector(x,individual_count)

  #now we need to sapply the evalIndividual function to each element of individuals
  return(sum(sapply(individuals,evalIndividual)))
}

#Run the Genetic Algorithm
GAmodel <- rbga.bin(size = chromosomesize, popSize = 200, iters = iter, mutationChance = 0.01, 
                    elitism = T, evalFunc = evalFunc)
#First show a summary
summary(GAmodel,echo=TRUE)
#Then extract the best solution from the GAmodel, copy/paste from the source code of the summary function
filter = GAmodel$evaluations == min(GAmodel$evaluations)
bestSolution = GAmodel$population[filter, , drop= FALSE][1,]

#Now split the solution in the individuals.
split_vector(bestSolution,individual_count)
```